# Antlr javascript with webpack

Tags: webpack, antlr4

I am trying to use webpack with antlr 4 javascript target. I am following this document. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

If I understand correctly , webpack will merge all the files from antlr4 javascript runtime librarty and the generated files (Lexer.js, Listener.js and Parser.js) in one single file. I need to include only this one file in my html.

I don't understand this part of the document where it's asking to exclude node.js module. Can someone please explain why this line is needed?

> In the `webpack.config` file, exclude node.js only modules using: `node: { module: "empty", net: "empty", fs: "empty" }`

I also don't have any custom listener or visitor. Can I ignore these steps. I am not creating any index.js file with entry point to my parsing code.

> - write your parse tree handling code by providing your custom listener or visitor, and associated code, using 'require' to load antlr.
> - create an index.js file with the entry point to your parsing code (or several if required).**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use antlr if an error with fs occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754585/how-to-use-antlr-if-an-error-with-fs-occurs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood why I need this configuration in webpack.config.js. If I don't have this configuration

```
node: {
        module: "empty",
        net:"empty",
        fs: "empty"
    },
```

I get below error while running webpack command:-

**ERROR in ./~/antlr4/FileStream.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /node_modules/antlr4
 @ ./~antlr4/FileStream.js 38:20-33**

The offending line is

```
var fs = isNodeJs ? require("FS") : null;
```