# How to use antlr if an error with fs occurs?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, antlr4

I have actually a problem with antlr. I use angular in visual studio code. I know how to include and write a grammar in a project. However, now I faced the problem that an error occurs while starting it:

"ERROR in ./node_modules/antlr4/CharStreams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\simon\antlrTestProject\node_modules\antlr4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/antlr4/FileStream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\simon\antlrTestProject\node_modules\antlr4'"

I found out that fs is no longer available in angular 6+. Unfortunetly I found no possibility to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antlr javascript with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618709/antlr-javascript-with-webpack)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the ANTLR JavaScript runtime outside of node.js, you need to configure webpack to exclude certain modules that exist in node.js, but not in the browser. From [the docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-get-the-runtime-in-my-browser):

> in the webpack.config file, exclude node.js only modules using: `node: { module: "empty", net: "empty", fs: "empty" }`

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with webpack. I also found in some discussions that: "node: { module: "empty", net: "empty", fs: "empty" }" is no longer possible. Is there maybe another solution?

Comment: @Simon Can you link to those discussions?

Comment: This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202948/update-to-angular-v6-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs

Comment: However I found a much simpler solution. If this problem occurs you can add to your package.json file the following:  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested solutions didn't work, there's a really not-recommended one that works for me if it's a angular CLI project .

Go to node_modules / @angular-devkit / build-angular / src /angular-cli-files /models / webpack-configs / browser.js

There's a json with a key-value:

```
node: null
```

Change that to :

```
node: { fs: "empty" }
```

That's obviously a horrible solution because :

- You have to make that change each time you update that package ;
- Your team has to be aware of that change and also apply it

If there were a way to force that change, it'd be a more viable solution